# Starting with learning python on colab.google agetting error shown in screen shot

Tags: python

i am getting this error when i am trying running this on "colab google". new to python so not exactly sure what could be the issue. it says display variable is missing.
error as below

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-13bc468cf9c3> in <module>()
      1 import turtle
----> 2 toy = turtle.Pen()
      3 for i in range(1,40):
      4   toy.circle(100)
      5   toy.right(10)

4 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   2021                 baseName = baseName + ext
   2022         interactive = 0
-> 2023         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   2024         if useTk:
   2025             self._loadtk()

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: here is my code if you are unable to see image  import turtle
toy = turtle.Pen()
for i in range(1,40):
  toy.circle(100)
  toy.right(10)
  toy.forward(5)

Comment: put code in question.

Comment: `colab.google` runs code on server and `tkinter` can access only monitor connected directly to this server - but servers usually don't have monitors because they don't need them. Even if server has monotior then only its admin can see what is on this monitor. If you want to run `turtle`, `tkinter`, or any other GUI framework (ie. `PyQT`, `PyGTK`, `wxPython`, `Kivy`, etc.) then you have to run it locally, not in colag.google (or any other cloud tool).